# Problems with c# lambda inference

Tags: c#, lambda

I wrote code like this:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c://test.txt")
   .Select(val => Console.WriteLine(val)
);
```

And I'm getting a compiler error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage.
>   Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

WriteLine can accept string and object as the parameter, that's probably a source of the error but how do I rewrite it?

Comment: Please consider rewriting the code to *not perform side-effects* in LINQ expressions/IEnumerable extension methods (this can have dire consequences when coupled with repeat-evaluations and lazy-sequences). While some people like `ForEach` (which is a List method, not an IEnumerable method), I recommend (and use religiously) `foreach (var elm in enumerable) { ... }` to indicate a side-effect process. As a bonus, there is no type inference error. Hint about the error: what is the *return type* of `WriteLine`?

Comment: @pst Can you explain more about potential side-effects you mentioned?

Comment: The ones that you run into when you least expect it ;-) The point is that there *is* a side-effect occurring. Imagine this: `IEnumerable<string> hardToMaintain() { return new [] {"a","b","c"}.Select(e => {Console.WriteLine("" + e); return "dummy"}; }; ... for(var i in hardToMaintain()) { Console.Writeline("bar"); }` What is the Output? `ForEach` *being a List method, and not a (lazy) IEnumerable method* "fixes" this by forcing the evaluation. However, it doesn't fix the fundamental problem, IMOHO. However, I find use `foreach...` to *indicate* that the code has (or may have) side-effects.

Comment: (There is a reason there is no `IEnumerable.ForEach` or `IEnumerable.Select(Action)` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer includes summary of other answers.

There isn't any problem with parameter type, problem is that Select method must return a value and it shouldn't be used in this case. ForEach would be the correct method, but only List has it, not every IEnumerable. So:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c://test.txt")
.ToList()
.ForEach(val => Console.WriteLine(val));
```

will do the trick (while incurring some overhead by converting to a list).

There is one more way: static Array.ForEach method. So my code will look like this:

```
Array.ForEach(
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c://test.txt"), val => Console.WriteLine(val)
);
```

Answer (score 7):

The `Select` method takes a `Func<TSource, TResult>`, but the return type of `Console.WriteLine` is `void`, i.e. no value at all. So in that case `TResult` would be `void`, and obviously, the return type of `Select` can't be `IEnumerable<void>` (i.e. "a sequence of nothing"...)

The lambda expression passed to `Select` **has** to return a value. If you just want to print the result of `File.ReadAllLines`, use a `for` or `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it by this code:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c://test.txt")
   .Select(val => {Console.WriteLine(val); return val;})
```

or

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c://test.txt")
   .ToList().ForEach(val => Console.WriteLine(val));
```

Comment: I don't see a reason for having a `List<T>.ForEach(Action<T>)` that don't equally apply to an `Enumerable.ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T>, Action<T>)`, so if I were to use `.ForEach()`, I'd create an extension method to make it available for any enumerable. Don't create a list if you don't need a list.

Comment: Why the ForEach extension isn't already on IEnumerable<T> in the framework puzzles me to this day.

Answer (score 3):

```cs
File.ReadAllLines(@"c://test.txt").ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Ever thought about memory consumption? If you make this with a big file it will be pushed twice into memory, cause `ReadAllLines()` will write it into an array and `ToList()` will read it from their into a new internal array.